# Error: Property left of ForInStatement is null?

Tags: reactjs, babylonjs

yesterday I was able to create my react babylon app with react-scripts. After updating babylon to 4.1.0 I receive the following error:

> ./node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.js TypeError:
>   /git/proconf_sa/node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.js: Property left of ForInStatement expected node to be of a type [“VariableDeclaration”,“LVal”] but instead got null

Any idea what the problem could be? I updated from version 3.1.0-alpha3.7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*I was facing the same problem, however using Angular.* I resolved by removing a package that uses **svg.js**@2.7.1 !!! From what you discover, this error is caused by the discontinued version of **svg.js**@2.7.1 !!! *Look inside your application that there is a package using this and remove it!*

**If using apexcharts update it, because it depends on svg.js!**

(NOTE: Sorry for possible errors in my writing, I'm Brazilian, I'm having to use Google translator to write this)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I can't find any package using svg.js. A colleague was able to build my app with my exact repository. So I assume the error is not related directly to my project.